# Allow user to run /bin/cp as another user on Unix

Tags: sudo

I have a user who is getting this problem:

```
Sorry, user myuser is not allowed to execute '/bin/cp /tmp/tempfile /applications/tomcat/instance/webapps/' as tomcat on myserver.on.our.network.
```

When running the following command:

```
sudo -u tomcat cp /tmp/tempfile /applications/tomcat/instance/webapps/
```

What change should I make (I assume with visudo) to allow the user to execute `/bin/cp` as the `tomcat` user? The user is a member of the `tomcat` group.

Thanks in advance

Rich

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
myuser        ALL = (tomcat) /bin/cp
```

is about as simple as it gets.  you can allow all members of the tomcat group to do it by putting

```
%tomcat       ALL = (tomcat) /bin/cp
```

That `ALL` there refers to the host in question; if you use this sudoers file on more than one host, it would be inappropriate, but if this sudoers file is particular to this host, it's safe enough and avoids issues with what the machine thinks its hostname is.

Comment: This doesn't work between different users. How we can deal with transfer file from one user to another. I want to do everything through sudo so changing permissions not that helpful.

Comment: @YasiruG I'm not sure I entirely understand your comment.  You might be better to write a new question, stating clearly (with examples) what you're trying to do, and linking this question in so others can see that you've already done some research.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I figured the issue. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

What are the rights and owner in /tmp/tempfile file ? You should have the right to modify a non by me created file (due to /tmp restrictions)

Comment: Forgive me, Dom, but I think you may be misreading the question.  Even if sudo was letting him run the command, the file in /tmp/ is the source file of the copy, not the destination; the destination's in /applications/tomcat, and it seems sensible to me that only tomcat can write into *that*.

Comment: Right, I re-read the question two times, and my answer is bad. Thanks to point it.